# How to execute alternatives loop (folder list) with alternatives by ansible

Tags: ansible

asking for Ansible guru to help figure out.
is it possible or not by Ansible

1. Jdk is downloaded and extracted to `/apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121`
2. binaries  - `/apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin`

**needed**

each binary in **/apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin**/java, java, javadoc,

... ....  and so on approximately 40 items, push to loop to alternatives programm

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin/java 1000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/{{ var }} {{var}} /apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin/{{var}} 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy, you just have to register the result of the [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) module and loop over it with `with_items`:

```yaml
- hosts: hosts
  tasks:
  - name: Find binaries
    find:
      paths: /apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin
    register: bins
  - name: Install alternatives
    command: "update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/{{ item.path|basename }} {{ item.path|basename }} {{ item.path }} 1000"
    with_items: "{{ bins.files }}"
```

Or, using the [`alternatives`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/alternatives_module.html) module:

```yaml
  - name: Install alternatives
    alternatives:
      name: "{{ item.path|basename }}"
      link: "/usr/bin/{{ item.path|basename }}"
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      priority: 1000
    with_items: "{{ bins.files }}"
```

With Ansible 2.5 or newer, it is [recommended to use `loop` instead of `with_items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items):

```
  - name: Install alternatives
    alternatives:
      name: "{{ item.path|basename }}"
      link: "/usr/bin/{{ item.path|basename }}"
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      priority: 1000
    loop: "{{ bins.files|flatten(levels=1) }}"
```

Comment: if I need to remove everything .. is it possibe to re use the module again ?

Comment: i guess this is not best practice ... but if i will use this approach - name: Remove SAP JDK New approach
  command: 'update-alternatives --remove "{{ item.path|basename}}" "/apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin/java8/bin/{{ item.path|basename }}"'
  with_items: "{{ bins.files }}"ice but what if i will use this approach

Comment: Why should it not be best practice? Of course you can use it.

Comment: i was told that this approach is not acceptable, we need to use loop approach. could you help to do that

Comment: I could, but that loops are explained in every basic shell scripting tutorial. And it wouldn't be ansible.

Comment: no no .. i made this change and it works

Comment: - name: Install alternatives
  alternatives:
    name: "{{ item.path|basename }}"
    link: "/usr/bin/{{ item.path|basename }}"
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    priority: 1000
  loop: "{{ bins.files }}"

Comment: I added a sample for the newer loop keyword of ansible. But if you already have it working I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: --slave "/usr/bin/jar"          "jar"           "/apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin/jar" 
--slave "/usr/bin/jarsigner"    "jarsigner"     "/apps/tools/jdk_1.8.121/bin/jarsigner"